# DHTMLX Scheduler Create or Edit

Tags: jquery, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using DHTMLX Scheduler in my MVC3 Project. Everything is fine but in that event scheduler page i have used one form for inputing some external data. So that the Event scheduler went to bottom of the page. If i click inside the window to create or edit new or existing event the screen blocker occurs for only the top of the page. Not with the current screen behind the pop-up.

Is there any better solution to do this? Please help me for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't actually reproduce this, but have you tried to place scheduler into the div with a fixed height?  e
.g.

```
<div>form or something...</div>
<div style="height: 900px">
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If it not helps, can you post a small demo where the problem could be tested?

Comment: Thanks Paul it worked for me when increasing the z-index size in the css file.